# Keyboard Enter doing two things at once

Tags: xna, c#, keyboard

In my `CheckKeyboard(Keys.Enter)` it does both of the things when I only want it to do one and the other on the next to enter click, I can't think of how to fix it. Here is the related code;

```
enum CurrentState
{
    Menu,
    NewGame,
    LevelSelect
}
private CurrentState _currentState = CurrentState.Menu;
public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Game1 game)
{
    keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        switch (_currentState)
            {
                //Error-  The name 'Menu' does not exist in the current context.
                case Menu:
                {
                }
            }
    prevKeyboard = keyboard;
}
public bool CheckKeyboard(Keys key)
{
    return (keyboard.IsKeyUp(key) && prevKeyboard.IsKeyDown(key));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case a 'state machine' system would be an alternative. (This way you can enhance it later more easily than using different flags).

First, define an enum with the possible states:

```
enum CurrentState {
     ShowOptions,
     SelectLevel
}
```

Then, define a field inside the current class, and initialise it with `ShowOptions`:

```
private CurrentState _currentState = CurrentState.ShowOptions;
```

In the `Update` method you'll have something like this:

```
switch(_currentState) {
    case CurrentState.ShowOptions:
    {
        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Enter))
        {
            if (selected == buttonList.Count - 2)
            {
                _currentState = CurrentState.SelectLevel;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case CurrentState.SelectLevel:
    {
        if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Enter))
        {
            if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 1) sChapter1 = "C3";
            if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 2) sChapter1 = "C2";
            if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 3) sChapter1 = "C1";

            // todo: advance to another state (maybe start the actual game?)
        }
        break;
    }           
}
```

It can be seen clearly how the states flow and go one after another. This allows you to have complex scenarios where you would need to go back to a state. For every new state, you just add an enum member and handle it inside the switch.

Comment: I added Menu to the Enum and now when I am trying to do case Menu: it is not working and says Menu doesn't exist in the current context, why does it say that?

Comment: Could you paste the code in http://pastebin.com ? It should work if you added the member the right way in the enum.

Comment: Well I don't want to give all of my code away so what is being used I will add to the question

Comment: I added what it is now.

Comment: Ah, OK. I am sorry, I typed the code without actually compiling it. You should haven't just copy it. Anyway, I've fixed it. I missed the "CurrentState." before each `case` statement. Also don't forget to `break;` at the end of each `case`. I've updated the code sample in my answer.

Comment: I didn't just copy, I figured out the CurrentState.Menu on my own but I forgot the break.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution for the code given.  Definitely not the best and I see a couple of other routes, but it should provide enough hints to make better.

Start by giving the class that contains this Update() Method a member variable.

```
private bool _isLevelSelect;
```

remove these from your current CheckKeyboard(Keys.Enter) implementation

```
if (selected == buttonList.Count - 2) Selected = "LevelSelect";

if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 1) sChapter1 = "C3";
if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 2) sChapter1 = "C2";
if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 3) sChapter1 = "C1";
```

add

```
if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Enter) && selected == buttonList.Count - 2)
{
    Selected = "LevelSelect";
    _isLevelSelect = true;
}

if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Enter) && _isLevelSelect)
{
    if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 1) sChapter1 = "C3";
    if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 2) sChapter1 = "C2";
    if (sChapter == chapterList.Count - 3) sChapter1 = "C1";
}
```

provide a way for user to cancel that selection

```
if (CheckKeyboard(Keys.Escape) && _isLevelSelect)
{
   _isLevelSelect = false;
}
```

Comment: It is still doing the same thing as it was.